# How do I use PostMessageServiceConnection in Android Chrome Custom Tabs?

Tags: android, google-chrome, postmessage, chrome-custom-tabs

There are no tutorials on how to achieve this, and the documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/customtabs/PostMessageServiceConnection is not helpful. There are very few posts on SO on this topic and most of them remain unanswered, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499759/chrome-customtabs-customtabscallback-onpostmessage-not-called).

I have tried to piece together some code by going through the documentation.

```
val token = CustomTabsSessionToken.getSessionTokenFromIntent(customTabsIntent.intent)
val postMessageServiceConnection = object: PostMessageServiceConnection(token)
postMessageServiceConnection.bindSessionToPostMessageService(this, PostMessageService::class.java.name)
```

I am able to open the link in the Custom Tabs Instance, but the bindSessionToPostMessageService function returns false, indicating the binding was not successful. Any open-ended code walkthroughs or suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue,  were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, no I didn't.